# Selecting records from one table

Tags: mysql

I have following table (tbl_product_rel):

```
id  product_id  attr_id
1      1           10
2      1           15
3      1           20
4      2           6
5      2           9
6      3           10
7      3           15
8      3           20
9      4           15
```

I want to get product_ids which have attr_ids exactly equal to 10,15,20. If I use MySQL IN

> SELECT DISTINCT(product_id) FROM `tbl_product_rel` WHERE attr_id IN
>   (10,15,20)

so I get also product_id which has attr_id equal to 15, but it does not have attr_ids 10 and 20.

Any ideas ?

Comment: This is correct query. Post your result please

Comment: You will not get them since they share the same product ids 1 and 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use query like this, but i don't know if this is the best solution :)

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_product_rel WHERE attr_id IN (10,15,20) GROUP BY product_id HAVING COUNT(product_id) = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you might get impression that your query does not work is probably due to `DISTINCT` function.
Think what is your desired output? You want get all product_id where attr_id is 10, 15 or 20. It means you want following ids:

```
id  product_id  attr_id
1      1 OK          10 
2      1 OK          15
3      1 OK          20
4      2 NO          6
5      2 NO          9
6      3 OK          10
7      3 OK          15
8      3 OK          20
9      4 OK          15
```

so the basic query without distinct should return:

```
1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4
```

if you use distinct, you will get unique ids:

```
1, 3, 4
```

I believe this is what you get.

Chances are you want "id" instead of "product_id".

UPDATE:

Ahh I might now what is your problem. You expect to get product_id which satisfies all 3 conditions. You cannot use `IN` because `IN` joins ids with `OR`. The query that you have written could be rewritten as:

```
`SELECT DISTINCT(product_id) FROM tbl_product_rel WHERE attr_id = 10 OR attr_id = 15 OR attr_id = 20`.
```

If you are sure that there are no duplicates (ie. 2 records with attr_id = 20), your solution would be

```
`SELECT product_id FROM tbl_product_rel WHERE attr_id IN (10, 15, 20) GROUP BY product_id HAVING count(*) = 3
```

but this will not work if you allow duplicates, for example in this scenario:

```
id  product_id  attr_id
1      1          10 
2      1          20
3      1          20
```

you will get 1 but you shouldn't (according to what you need). Plase let me know if you allow such scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want only product_ids with all three attribute ids. You can do it with some ugly subqueries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(product_id) FROM tbl_product_rel
  WHERE product_id IN 
    (SELECT product_id FROM tbl_product_rel WHERE attr_id=10)
  AND product_id IN
    (SELECT product_id FROM tbl_product_rel WHERE attr_id=15)
  AND product_id IN
    (SELECT product_id FROM tbl_product_rel WHERE attr_id=20)
```

You could also do some uglier joins.

Comment: If I understand right he's looking for IDs that have attributes 10 AND 15 AND 20, but not 10 or 15 or 20. Therefore we need a query that makes sure it checks each of those values. Between will return on any of those values. As well, it's possible there's other values that he didn't mention between 10 and 20.

Answer (score 0):

Remove distinct function:

`SELECT product_id FROM tbl_product_rel WHERE attr_id IN (10,15,20)`